# Rope tree that returns node that can be used to find the position and who's parent is a token

Tags: data-structures, tree, compiler-construction, editor, red-black-tree

I am trying to write a compiler/code editor.

To speed up the process I want a red and black tree that returns a node which I can then use to get the strings under it, and it's position value, and use it's parent node as a place to store a token (such as alphanumeric_word or left_parenthesis).

I am having trouble finding the best way to go about this.

I basically want something that can do the following:

```
tree.insert("01234567890123456789",0);
node = tree.at(10);
tree.insert("string",5);

node.index(); //should be 10+length("string")
node.value(); //should be '0'
node.tokenPtr.value; //should point to a token with the value of NUMBER
```

I am looking for the simplest implementation of such a tree that I could modify since these can be frustrating to build and debug from scratch.

The following code is sort of what I am looking for (it has parent nodes), but it lacks an indexing feature for index look up. This is needed because I want to create a map that uses the node as it's key and node.index() as it's sorting value so that I don't have to update the keys in that map.

[[archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/TStorage/page2.html]]

I have tried to look at sgi's rope implimentation, but the code is overwhelming and difficult to understand.

This tutorial seems to be helpfull, however it also doesn't provide a doubly linked tree which I think can be used to find the index of a node:

[[eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_rbtree.aspx]]

**Update:**
I have found an implementation that has a parent node, however it still lacks an index count property:

[[web.mit.edu/~emin/Desktop/ref_to_emin/www.old/source_code/red_black_tree/index.html]]

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution and another that might work.

You have to use the sgi stl rope mutable_begin()+(index) iterator.

There is also this function, however I am still having trouble analyzing the sgi rope code to see what it does:

mutable_reference_at(index)